# $\mathcal C(X)$ is complete with respect to sup norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness, normed-spaces

I am following the lecture note on functional analysis given by our instructor. There he claimed that if $X$ is compact and Hausdorff then $\mathcal C (X)$ is complete with respect to the sup norm. I did that proof on my own in the similar way that is used to prove that $\mathcal C([a,b])$ is complete with respect to the sup norm. But I never used Hausdorff condition anywhere in my proof. Is it of no importance here? Any suggestion regarding this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whether $X$ is Hausdorff is indeed irrelevant. And compactness is only needed to be sure that all continuous functions on $X$ are bounded, so that the sup norm is defined. The meat of the proof is "the (locally) uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous", and that uses no assumptions on the domain (except that it be endowed with a topology, so that we can even speak of continuity).

Comment: There is also a process called "Hausdorffization": https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Hausdorffization. Basically, every topological space has a "largest" Hausdorff quotient, and the process of Hausdorffizying spaces is functorial. In fact, $C(X)$ and $C(X_H)$ are always isometrically isomorphic, for a topological space $X$ and is Hausdorfizzied (I'm inventing words) version $X_H$. So it is not really a problem to only take Hausdorff $X$, as the results can translate to general spaces by Hausdorfizzizling.